# Error while connecting to documentum source

Tags: documentum, dfc, documentum6.5, documentum-dfs, documentum-dfc

I am new to documentum,can any one help me how to resolve the following error

```
DfException:: THREAD: Thread-694; MSG: [DFC_BOF_CLASS_CACHE_INIT_ERROR] Failed to initialize class cache.; ERRORCODE: ff; NEXT: null
at com.documentum.fc.client.impl.bof.cache.NullClassCacheManager.checkCacheConsistency(NullClassCacheManager.java:46)
at com.documentum.fc.client.impl.bof.compoundclass.CompoundClassMgr.getImpClass(CompoundClassMgr.java:66)
at com.documentum.fc.client.impl.objectmanager.AbstractPersistentObjectFactory.getCompoundClassEntry(AbstractPersistentObjectFactory.java:39)
at com.documentum.fc.client.impl.objectmanager.PObjectFactoryWithAspects.makeObject(PObjectFactoryWithAspects.java:49)
at com.documentum.fc.client.impl.objectmanager.PersistentObjectManager.getObjectFromServer(PersistentObjectManager.java:356)
at com.documentum.fc.client.impl.objectmanager.PersistentObjectManager.getObject(PersistentObjectManager.java:311)
at com.documentum.fc.client.impl.session.Session.getObject(Session.java:963)
at com.documentum.fc.client.impl.session.SessionHandle.getObject(SessionHandle.java:653)
at com.gsk.rd.datacoe.documentum.DocumentumBot.processBotLogic(DocumentumBot.java:193)
at com.gsk.rd.datacoe.bots.BaseBot.processMessage(BaseBot.java:542)
at com.gsk.rd.datacoe.bots.BaseBot.fetchMessages(BaseBot.java:460)
at com.gsk.rd.datacoe.bots.BaseBot$1.run(BaseBot.java:185)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I am using dfc.properties,can any one help me what is the cause of the above error

my dfc.properties file is

```
dfc.data.dir=./dfc
dfc.registry.mode=file
dfc.search.ecis.enable=false
dfc.search.ecis.host=
dfc.search.ecis.port=
dfc.tokenstorage.dir=./dfc/apptoken
dfc.tokenstorage.enable=false
dfc.docbroker.host[0]=random host_name
dfc.docbroker.port[0]=1489


#Additions 3/22
dfc.security.keystore.file=./dfc/dfc.keystore
dfc.session.secure_connect_default=try_native_first

dfc.globalregistry.repository[0]=random docbase
dfc.globalregistry.username=username
dfc.globalregistry.password=password
#dfc.cache.object.size=100
#dfc.session.pool.expiration_interval=10
```

does any values in dfc.properties is causing the above error?? please help me

Comment: Do you have permissions to write in ./dfc folder?

Comment: yes i am having permissions for the ./dfc folder

Answer (score 0):

Just to be sure: do you have actual values for host and global registry properties?

Comment: I am  having the actual host and global registry properties,but I couldn't figure out the cause of this error,can u help me??

Answer (score 0):

A DFC client only has one global registry hence this is wrong

`dfc.globalregistry.repository[0]=random docbase`

and should be

`dfc.globalregistry.repository=random docbase`

Comment: since it is an array,we can use multiple docbases and those docbases should be specified in dfc.properties,my dfc client works well with multiple docbases which are included in dfc.properties